# Bash script to delete all but N files when sorted alphabetically

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

It's hard to explain in the title.

I have a bash script that runs daily to backup one folder into a zip file. The zip files are named **world**`YYYYMMDD`**.zip** with `YYYYMMDD` being the date of backup. What I want to do is delete all but the 5 most recent backups. Sorting the files alphabetically will list the oldest ones first, so I basically need to delete all but the last 5 files when sorted in alphabetical order.

Comment: Is this meant to be done manually whenever you feel you have too many backups, or every time the bash script is run?

Comment: @chaz8705 I will be using it both ways

Comment: Be aware that most of these answers will fail with filenames that contain spaces.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The following line should do the trick.

```
ls world*.zip | head -n -5 | xargs -r rm
```

- `ls world*.zip`: List the files [alphabetically](https://serverfault.com/q/122737/42849)
- `head -n -5`: Filter out all lines except the last 5
- `xargs -r rm`: remove each given file. `-r`: don't run `rm` if the input is empty

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
find /your/directory -name 'world*.zip' -mtime +5 | xargs rm
```

Test it before. This should remove all `world*.zip` files older than 5 days. So a different logic than you have.

Comment: Even though this makes the most sense, I don't want to delete based on file date. If the backup script fails I still want to keep the 5 most recent, so aioobe's answer is the best for me.

Comment: The {} really should be either escaped or in quotes.
I know it works in this case, but it is still good practice and recommended by the man page.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test it right now because I don't have a Linux machine, but I think it should be:

```
rm `ls -A | head -5`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls | grep ".*[\.]zip" | sort | tail -n-5 | while read file; do rm $file; done
```

- `sort` sorts the files
- `tail -n-5` returns all but the 5 most recent
- the `while` loop does the deleting

Comment: No. This will remove 5 files. Author wants all but 5 and grep -c counts files.

Comment: @Benoit Was a typo which I've fixed.

Comment: probably do `echo world*.zip | sort | tail -n -5 | xargs rm` is more efficient.

Comment: The `grep` is unnecessary. @Benoit: The `echo` outputs all on one line so the sort is ineffective.

Answer (score 0):

`ls world*.zip | sort -r | tail n+5 | xargs rm`

`sort -r` will sort in reversed order, so the newest will be at the top

`tail n+5` will output lines, starting with the 5th

`xargs rm` will remove the files.  Xargs is used to pass stdin as parameters to rm.